# Desempate de selección por medio de otro campo

Tags: sql-server

Quiero modificar el siguiente código para que valide si hay dos o mas registros con el mismo `IdSolicitud` pero con distinto `NombreCliente`.

Se tiene que actualizar el estatus a: En progreso, al que haya sido cargado primero (Hay un campo llamado FechaCarga):

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM PPS_Balanceador_CA
    WHERE Prioridad = 'Alta'
    AND Estatus = 'Pendiente'
)
BEGIN
    -- Tomar los registros con prioridad alta y estatus pendiente
    UPDATE PPS_Balanceador_CA
    SET Estatus = 'En Progreso'
    WHERE IdSolicitud = (
        SELECT MIN(CAST(IdSolicitud AS INT))
        FROM PPS_Balanceador_CA
        WHERE Prioridad = 'Alta'
        AND Estatus = 'Pendiente'
    )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Tomar los registros con prioridad normal y estatus pendiente
    UPDATE PPS_Balanceador_CA
    SET Estatus = 'En Progreso'
    WHERE IdSolicitud = (
        SELECT MIN(CAST(IdSolicitud AS INT))
        FROM PPS_Balanceador_CA
        WHERE Prioridad = 'Normal'
        AND Estatus = 'Pendiente'
    )
END
```

Comment: Si entiendo bien, solo tienes que actualizar una fila cada vez que ejecutas el código. El IdSolicitud se puede repetir pero el cliente puede ser diferente o igual. En caso de  que sea igual ¿se actualizarían las filas en que sea el mismo cliente?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que intentaste??? ese es tu requerimiento, cual es tu problema???

Comment: No. Debe actualizar tantas filas cumplan con el criterio de Prioridad Alta, estatus Pendiente. Si hay varios registros que cumplan esa condición, se deben actualizar los que tengan el Idsolicitud Minimo. Si hay registros que cumplen lo de IdSolicitud Minimo, pero con fecha de carga distinta, se deben actualizar los que tengan fecha Carga Minima.